# Is there a reason to convert arguments to a local variable?

Tags: javascript

Is there a reason I shouldn't do

```
function bla(args){
  use(args);
}
```

and do this: ?

```
function bla(args){
  var loacalArgs = args;
  use(loacalArgs);
}
```

Are there places one is preferred over the other?

Comment: This is not a very good example. Best practice for this situation is to not even call bla(args) and go straight to use(args).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reason to do that, because `args` is alreayd a local variable.

```
function bla(args) {
   var localArgs = args;   //<-- This variable is as local as the other one
}
```

The only reason to refer to the same variable through another name is when you want to copy the reference/value, and modify one of them, eg:

```
function validate(word) {
    var originalWord = word;
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    if (word === originalWord) return 'At least one uppercase char is required!';
    // ... do something with both variables
```

Answer (score 0):

DO you mean you should copy the argument into another variable?

Its not necessary, since args itself is a local variable

Answer (score 0):

One reason appear to me is that when I want to modify the argument while also want to keep an original copy. otherwise I don't think I have a reason to write additional line of code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to copy your  `args` to another variable `loacalArgs` unless you are doing some modifications to the original variable `args`.